# How to get the path length between a child and parent node using skos:broader*

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I have the following query getting the terminal leaf nodes from a parent category

```
select distinct ?subcat where {
  ?subcat  skos:broader* category:Buildings_and_structures_in_France_by_city .
  optional { ?subsubcat skos:broader ?subcat }
} 
group by ?subcat
having count(?subsubcat) = 0
```

How do I get the path length between the child node `?subcat` and the parent node `category:Buildings_and_structures_in_France_by_city` such that the output would be something like?

[image]

Comment: If there's a unique path, then you can do this.  If there are multiple paths, then you can't.

Comment: I don't think your link to another post goes where you intend it to.

Comment: I removed it. Regarding the unique path, how could it be done ?

Comment: See [Calculate length of path between nodes?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5198889/1281433)

Comment: Here is the real problem with skos:broader*, let say the root category is Category:Buildings_and_structures_in_France, and I want to get all french POIs. one of the subcats is category:Category:Ancient_Roman_buildings_and_structures_in_France, the skos:broader* will go down on this one and I end up fgetting POIs not in France but in Italy. That is why I need to filter by some path length

Comment: Also, rather than doing `optional { ... }` and `having ...`, you could just do `filter not exists { ?subsubcat skos:broader ?subcat }`.

Comment: Thanks, but any suggestion regarding my problem. It had caused me a big headache how to obtain French POIs and not being deviated to other countries when I use skos:broader*

Comment: "regarding my problem":  the title of the question is "How to get the path length between a child and parent node using skos:broader*" and I think my comments have been relevant there.  But if the real task is to find buildings of interest, why not find places/buildings that are in the category category:Buildings_and_structures_in_France_by_city or a subcategory of it, and then, since some of those might not actually be in France, filter the buildings for ones that *are* in France?

Comment: Have already done this but how do I know which one is not in France. I was hoping to use the path length as a filtering tool.

Comment: I don't think that path length will be a particularly helpful filtering tool there.  the categories aren't intended to form a hierarchy, as they're just topics, and there can be cycles, so lengths aren't well-defined anyhow.  For filtering, you could find some geographic properties and filter based on what's available.  it won't be perfect, but you may have some luck.

Comment: Alright, will do, Thanks again. How about the other question I posted today? It is a similar problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29414522/finding-corresponding-state-for-pois-using-skosbroader

Answer (score 2):

If the real task is finding buildings and structures in France, then you can ask for things in that category of some appropriate types.  E.g.,

```sql
select distinct ?building where {
  values ?type { dbpedia-owl:ArchitecturalStructure
                 dbpedia-owl:Building
                 dbpedia-owl:Place }
  ?building a ?type ;
            dcterms:subject/skos:broader* category:Buildings_and_structures_in_France_by_city 
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20distinct%20%3Fbuilding%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20values%20%3Ftype%20%7B%20dbpedia-owl%3AArchitecturalStructure%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbpedia-owl%3ABuilding%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbpedia-owl%3APlace%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%3Fbuilding%20a%20%3Ftype%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dcterms%3Asubject%2Fskos%3Abroader*%20category%3ABuildings_and_structures_in_France_by_city%20%0D%0A%7D%20%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

That gets just about 700 results.  If you find some that aren't France, take a look at their values and see what you could exclude them based on.  Perhaps you could add a filter to restrict latitude and longitude, or country values, etc.

Comment: That is what I have been doing, I just thought getting the path length may be a more efficient filtering technique, thanks though

Comment: Your question didn't mention that you were already doing this.

Comment: my bad, wanted to keep it simple and more right to the point of path length but you are right, i should have.